# Togglz console error 403 Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, togglz

I'm trying to run Togglz Console on Spring Boot, but I get this on screen:

```
(type=Forbidden, status=403). You are not allowed to access the Togglz Console.
```

I just noticed many people have the same problem, and some solutions worked for them. But I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here my code:

**MyFeatures**

```
  public enum MyFeatures implements Feature {

    @EnabledByDefault
    @Label("The list of employees can be displayed")
    SHOW_LIST,

    @Label("Second Feature")
    FEATURE_TWO;

    public boolean isActive() {
        return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
    }


@Bean
public FeatureProvider featureProvider() {
    return new EnumBasedFeatureProvider(MyFeatures.class);
}}
```

**MyTogglzConfiguration**

```
public class MyTogglzConfiguration implements TogglzConfig {
@Override
public Class<? extends Feature> getFeatureClass() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public StateRepository getStateRepository() {
    return null;
}


@Override
public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
    return new UserProvider() {
        @Override
        public FeatureUser getCurrentUser() {
            return new SimpleFeatureUser("admin", true);
        }
    };
}}
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
        <artifactId>togglz-console</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
        <artifactId>togglz-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
togglz:
enabled:true # Enable Togglz for the application.
feature-enums:# Comma-separated list of fully-qualified feature enum class names.
feature-manager-name:# The name of the feature manager.
features:# The feature states. Only needed if feature states are stored in application properties.
HELLO_WORLD:true
REVERSE_GREETING:true
REVERSE_GREETING.strategy:username
REVERSE_GREETING.param.users:user2, user3
features-file:# The path to the features file that contains the feature states. Only needed if feature states are stored in external properties file.
features-file-min-check-interval:# The minimum amount of time in milliseconds to wait between checks of the file's modification date.
cache:
enabled:false # Enable feature state caching.
time-to-live:0 # The time after which a cache entry will expire.
time-unit:milliseconds # The time unit as java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit enum name (one of "nanoseconds", "microseconds", "milliseconds", "seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days").
console:
enabled:true # Enable admin console.
path:/togglz-console # The path of the admin console when enabled.
feature-admin-authority:ROLE_ADMIN # The name of the authority that is allowed to access the admin console.
secured:false # Indicates if the admin console runs in secured mode. If false the application itself should take care of securing the admin console.
endpoint:
id:togglz # The endpoint identifier.
enabled:true # Enable actuator endpoint.
sensitive:true # Indicates if the endpoint exposes sensitive information.
```

I'd appreciate if someone could help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found what I did wrong, so my tips:

> 1. No need for MyTogglzConfiguration class
> 2. Change application.properties to application.yml
> 3. Use either Spring Security for togglz-console or make is disabled.

My updated application properties (application.yml):

```
   togglz.console.enabled: true

   togglz:
     feature-enums: service.Features
     console:
      path: /togglz-console
      secured: false
```

Comment: but what if there is a need to access control the feature toggles? Most likely not everyone is allowed to access the feature toggle right?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have togglz related unit test jar file in the classpath.

In my case I got togglz-junit.2.1.0.Final.jar in the classpath.